# Why is Qt Creator's core a plugin?

Tags: qt, plugins, architecture, qt-creator

Do you have a clear explanation why they have chosen the core of the application to be a plugin like the other components, and not just a basic shared library?
I cannot see any clear advantages, besides the 'coolness' of the design.

Comment: Where did you read that it is a plugin?

Comment: Just look at the code, it's loaded as any other plugin

Comment: @Laurent http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtcreator-extending/qtcreator-api.html documents this for example.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I got an answer from the developers themselves:

> Qt Creator doesn't aim to be an application framework. "Core" being a
>   plugin has mostly academical reasons, though e.g. one practical
>   advantage is that in that way the core of Qt Creator automatically has
>   a "version", and the check if a plugin is compatible with Qt Creator
>   is done the exact same way as with any other plugin dependencies. Also
>   the whole startup initialization (including the initialization of the
>   other plugins) is done the same way which leads to same concept and
>   there is less to learn.

Answer (score 5):

As to "why" we can only guess. In [their own documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtcreator-extending/index.html) they state:

> Qt Creator is extensible in various ways. For example, Qt Creator
>   architecture is based on a plugin loader, which means that all
>   functionality beyond plugin loading is implemented in plugins.
>   However, you can extend and tweak many parts of Qt Creator without the
>   need to resort to coding in C++ and implementing such a plugin.

So from this one could gather that this choice was made with extensibility in mind. I'm not sure if the answer to "why is the core a plugin?" is anything more than "why not?". If you are creating your application to be, as they say, a plugin loader, then why not keep it as "light" on functionality as possible and make the core a plugin as well.